# Passing QList as output argument reference

Tags: qt, arguments, output, qt5

I have a function that return a bool to indicate if the process worked or not and i would like to have 2 outputs arguments passed to it by reference.

Here is the definition of my function:

```
bool LoadIndexes(QList<SourceIndex> &indexes, Logger &logger);
```

And here how i tried to use it:

```
QList<SourceIndex> indexes;
if (SourceIndex::LoadIndexes(indexes, logger)) { // logger is a member already instantiated

}
```

But i am getting an error `call to non-static member function without an object argument` related to my QList here and don't understand it.

Comment: I think `SourceIndex::LoadIndexes method` is not static method.
Your error will occur when you called non-static method

Comment: Oh my, i can't believe i made this mistake, sorry and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `SourceIndex::LoadIndexes method` is non-static method.